# Is there a simple way to convert an Antergos system to an Arch system?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, antergos

I've been running Antergos XFCE for years now. As I'm sure everyone knows, the Antergos project ended in May. I was planning to jump to a different distribution last summer, but then life happened and I'm still running Antergos.

This hasn't been a problem, until recently. The package `pamac` conflicts with the latest version of `pacman`.

I'm curious if there is a simple way to convert my system to a pure Arch system. I've done a fair amount of googling but haven't found much.

Is this as simple as removing the antergos repos from my `pacman.conf`? If I do remove them, what happens to the packages on my system installed from  the antergos repos?

Comment: I would rather recommend to make a clean, fresh install of official Arch.iso

Comment: @JoKeR I'm sure this is the best thing to do, and I plan on doing it soon.

Answer (score 3):

1.Add Arch repository to /etc/pacman.conf

```
[arch]
SigLevel = PackageRequired
Include = /etc/pacman.d/arch-mirrorlist
```

2.Create /etc/pacman.d/arch-mirrorlist file

```
Server = https://mirrors.kernel.org/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
```

3.Update your system:

```
sudo pacman -Syyuu
```

4.Pray for the old gods and the new ones.

Comment: Tried that, got `error: failed retrieving file 'arch.db' from mirrors.kernel.org : The requested URL returned error: 404`

Comment: @robertc try a mirror from: https://www.archlinux.org/mirrorlist/

Comment: Tried that, picked a UK mirror, same error.  Looking at all the files I have in `/etc/pacman.d/` I already have a list of Arch repos in a file called `mirrorlist` which is included in `pacman.conf` under `[extra]`

Answer (score 3):

This should probably be another comment, but I don't have the reputation...

All the recommendations for adding

```
[arch]
SigLevel = PackageRequired
Include = /etc/pacman.d/arch-mirrorlist
```

and

```
/etc/pacman.d/arch-mirrorlist
Server = https://mirrors.kernel.org/archlinux/$repo/os/$arch
```

just created errors:

```
error: failed retrieving file 'arch.db' from mirrors.kernel.org : The requested URL returned error: 404
error: failed to update arch (failed to retrieve some files)
```

This was already in pacman.conf, and gets all the Arch files

```
[core]
Include = /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist
```

I just needed to remove the Antergos stuff and the updates worked!